# Adding data in linked list using for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to add data into a linked list using for loop.
what i expect is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
O/P i'm getting is 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct NODE
{
    int data;
    NODE *next;
};
int main()
{
    int i,j=0;
    NODE *start=NULL,*ptr,*temp;
    for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        ptr = new NODE;
        ptr->data=i;
        ptr->next=NULL;
        if(start==NULL)
            start=ptr;
        else
        {
            temp=start;
            while(temp->next!=NULL)
                temp=temp->next;
            temp->next=ptr;
        }
    }
    temp=start;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<start->data<<"  ";
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what is wrong with this program??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is this loop that is wrong

```
temp=start;
while(temp->next!=NULL)
{
    cout<<start->data<<"  ";
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

Change it the following way

```
for ( temp = start; temp; temp = temp->next ) cout << temp->data << ' ';
```

Or if you want to use while-loop then

```
temp = start;
while ( temp )
{
    cout << temp->data << '  ';
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Also instead of name temp I would use name next. For example

```
for ( NODE *next = start; next; next = next->next ) cout << next->data << ' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the first (start) node every time.

You should change:

```
cout<<start->data<<"  ";
```

to:

```
cout<<temp->data<<"  ";
      ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are printing "start->data" and not temp->data

Answer (score 0):

you show only 1 that is in i
ypu don't insert data from user if we add this code then we can get data from user

```
 for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    ptr = new NODE;
    cout<<"enter data";
    cin>>data;
    ptr->data=data;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
        start=ptr;
    else
    {
        temp=start;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
            temp=temp->next;
        temp->next=ptr;
    }
}
```